# FreeBSD 11.2: how to resize the boot options menu on a UEFI/GPT/ZFS machine?

Tags: freebsd, uefi, boot-loader, zfs

Is there a way to resize the boot options menu in Freebsd 11.2 on a UEFI/GPT/ZFS machine (zfs-on-root)?

On multiple machines, the installation resulted in the boot options menu being rendered in a tiny font positioned at the top left of the screen (see ‘photo a’ at bottom).

Changing the font size in **/etc/rc** and **/boot/loader.conf** does not fix it. Changing the font size in **/etc/rc.conf** only affects userland.

The boot menu loader prompt offers some graphical output mode options (**gop**) which did not work either. Mode 3 was the only one that the prompt accepted, but it didn’t fix the problem. The other modes caused the screen to go blank and freeze. **Etc** opens the loader prompt. There you can view and set the various graphical output modes.

These are the results from earlier:

```
OK gop list
    available modes
    “”
    “”
OK gop set 3
Failed to start image provided by ZFS(1)
```

Any thoughts?

Photo a
[image]

Comment: The "tiny font" is caused by the very high resolution (probably 1920x1080). I have the same issue that using `gop set` just kills my computer and requires a hard reboot. you could try using `mode` instead but I still have to find a working solution to set a decent screen resolution.